# how to prevent controls from resizing when resolution changes..?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

IDE: Visual Studio 2010,  C#.net 4.0 winforms application

My project is build on 1366x768 screen resolution and running fine on it, this application rich of  of winforms and user controls and custom controls.

Problem #1:

How to handle, When I run the same application on smaller resolution for eg. (1200x800) The right part of application is not visible on that screen.

Problem #2:

How to handle, when I run the same application on bigger resolution screen for eg. 1920x1080, the controls are stretching  non proportionally,

for problem 2, please tell me how to prevent controls from stretching and changing its location, I have observed that the location and size of control is changed, which I don't want, can you suggest me how to handle this problem.

also provide me a generic solution for #1 and #2, I have searched that anchor and dock is one way to handle it but still I am not satisfied with those solutions because of having rich of controls on it.

Comment: This [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976612/when-screen-resolution-changes-the-panel-and-its-child-control-display-inside-th) might help to fix your case.

Comment: Perhaps this link From MSDN will help: [Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605(v=vs.110).aspx)